# Creating websites templates. Spacing on two separate designs is different although it should be the same

Tags: html, css

My templates are almost same in design besides a an additional gap in spacing I can not explain.

[image]

First template, it is divided into two parts, left has some text and right has buttons on it.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
            <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <nav>
                <div id = "banner"> </div>                      
                <div class="container_nav">
                    <a href="link" class="myButton">Something2</a>          
                </div>
            </nav>

            <h2 style="position: relative; top:80px"> Topicus</h2>      

            <div id = "b">
                <div style="width: 100%;">              
                    <div style="float:left; width: 50%; ">
                        <div style="position: relative; left: 15px; top:0px">
                            <p> Random Text </p>            
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div style="float:left;">
                        <div style="position: relative; top: 15px; left:20px;">
                        <a href="link2">Sapien</a>                      
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="clear:both"></div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Second template, this one isn't divided vertically but horizontally. With text first and then some buttons after.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
            <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <nav>
                <div id = "banner"> </div>              
                <div class="container_nav">
                    <a href="link" class="myButton">Something</a>                   
                </div>
            </nav>

            <h2 style="position: relative; top:80px"> Venieie </h2>         

            <div id = "b"> 
                <div style="position: relative; left: 15px;">
                        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
                </div>              
                <div>
                    <a href="link2" class="button_class">this</a>               
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

After the page title in the `<h2>`, each page has a `<div>` of class b. 
`#b` is exactly the same in both documents.

```
#b {

    top: 70px;
    position: relative;

    }
```

Although the only thing separating text block from the title in both designs is `#b` spacer/divisor the distance when displayed is different for both of these templates. I am out of ideas what is the root of it, I can fix it by having 2 different values of `top:`, but obviously this isn't the right way to do it.

Comment: think about "float". it cause!

Comment: It's due to [margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing). The template _without_ the floated elements will collapse the margins (less space) while the one _with_ the floated elements will not (more space).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you use float, the ordering of arrange html tags is different. in one template, you used float and the other not.